# Passing Class objects to Drools Rules (drt) file

Tags: drools, kie

I'm using Drools  Template for decision making, I have created instance of class and passed the class objects to Kie session using insert

In the drt file, I tried to compare the Template columns with Class objects and certain parameters have passed threshold , then setting the Priority based on the value in the Template file

Format of the Template file (Excel)

```
Parameter     Mountpoint       Threshold      Severity
Disk            /root           80              MINOR
Disk            /tmp            90              MAJOR

My class Capacity {

private String component;
private String subComponent;
privat Integer value;

public String getComponent() {
            return component;
        }
        public void setComponent(String component) {
            this.component = component;
        }
        public String getSubComponent() {
            return subComponent;
        }
        public void setSubComponent(String subComponent) {
            this.subComponent = subComponent;
        }
        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

public Capacity()        
        {
            super();
            this.component = component;
            this.subComponent = subComponent;
            this.value = value;
        } 

}
```

In another class, I'm initiating KieSession and injecting the capacity Class objects and loads the Templates file
Drool

```
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    KieSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeSessionConfiguration();
    sessionConfig.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get( ClockType.PSEUDO_CLOCK.getId() ) );
    try {
        loadRuleTemplate(DATA_FILE, RULE_TEMPLATE_FILE, "OperationalMeasurement", 2, 1);
    } catch (IOException errorMsg) {
        log.error(errorMsg.getMessage());       }
    InternalKnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addPackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());       
    KieSession kieSession =  kbase.newKieSession(sessionConfig, null);
    sessionClock = ksession.getSessionClock();
    ksession.insert(Capacity);
    ksession.fireAllRules();
    ksession.dispose();
```

Rules file

```
template header
Parameter
Mountpoint
Threshold
Severity

package com.test.drools;

dialect "java"

template "OperationalMeasurement"

rule "Check_Threshold_@{row.rowNumber}"
ruleflow-group "capacityManagement"
salience 500
when
   $capacity: Capacity(component == "@{Parameter}" && subComponent == "@{Mountpoint}" && value >= "@{Threshold}")
  then   
    System.out.println("Thresold cross for Component and Priority is set " + @{Severity}"); 
end
end template
```

When i run this, component is treated as literal string instead of Capacity class variable and though i dont get any error , it simply prints all the contents of the drt file in the console.
And I dont seems to get the Sysout statements

Comment: Could you please paste at least one of the generated rules once the template is expanded? I also noticed that you are using a `ruleflow-group` in your template, but you are never activating it when executing your `KieSession`. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti..this is the output 'c.b.d.a.capacity.capacityEventHandler  : package com.test.drools;
dialect "java"
import com.test.drools.Capacity;
rule "Check_Threshold_2"
salience 500
when
   $capacity: Capacity(component == "Disk" && subComponent == "/tmp" && value >= 90)
  then   
    System.out.println("Thresold crossed for Component::" +component + " and Priority is set " + Major"); 
end

Comment: It just prints the entire rule file contents, just that it instead of Template fields, it substitutes with actual values from the templates, if there are two records in the templates, rules are triggered twice . also i removed ruleflow-group from drl file, still the same result

Answer (score 1):

> component is treated as literal string instead of Capacity class variable

Not sure what you mean by that. what "component" is being treated as a literal?

According to the generated rule you added as a comment, there are some errors in the rules being generated:

```
    System.out.println("Thresold crossed for Component::" +component + " and Priority is set " + Major");
```

In the line above, "component" is expected to be a variable, but there is no variable with that name. There is also a missing quote before the "Major" string.
I would suggest you to change your template to something like this:

```
rule "Check_Threshold_@{row.rowNumber}"
ruleflow-group "capacityManagement"
salience 500
when
   $capacity: Capacity(component == "@{Parameter}" && subComponent == "@{Mountpoint}" && value >= "@{Threshold}")
  then   
    System.out.println("Threshold cross for Component:: @{Parameter} and Priority is set to @{Severity}"); 
end
end template
```

That should generate valid DRL.

One other thing that worth mentioning is that for some weird reason that I never fully understood, Drools will not complain if there are errors in your Knowledge Bases (i.e. errors in the DRL files). You **have to** check for errors by yourself before using a Knowledge Base. The `KnowledgeBuilder` class has a `hasErrors()` method and a `getResults()` methods that you can use to check for errors. If you are using a `KieContainer`, then you have a `verify()` method you can use. How are you loading your DRL into the `KieBase`?

Hope it helps,